# Is there a word referring to a given animal species' fear or lack thereof of humans?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

Some animal species are very unafraid of humans, willing to be approached or even picked up. Dodos, famously, and I've noticed with insects as well that some want nothing to do with you whereas other species will happily sit on your hand for minutes at a time. Other species, like say most songbirds, will run if you come within ten feet of them.

Is there a word in English, maybe a technical ethological term, to refer to an animal species' fear or lack thereof of humans? I would have guessed "anthropophobic", but I can't find any references using that term in specifically this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "lack thereof of humans"? Can you please simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean if there's a specific word for animal's fear of humans? I Don't think so. As fear is a complex emotion and present within species of high intelligence such as most mammals/birds/reptiles etc. Some speices of these animals  are too dumb to discern danger (espeically herbivores) . That happens due to them living in an environment where they thrive and doesn't have any predators/competition.So when they see humans they don't react. Insects are even dumber, they only react to certain disturbances in the atmosphere around them, so if we ,for e.g lay a finger infront of an ant it climbs on it and continues to go on.However this maybe close to what you're looking for:-

> Skittish
>   IPA: /ˈskɪtɪʃ/
>   (T-flapping) IPA: [ˈskɪɾɪʃ]
>   Adjective
>   Easily scared or startled; timid.
>   The cat likes people he knows, but he is skittish around strangers.
>   Wiktionary

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about insects, but if larger creatures are unafraid of humans it's normally because they live in an environment where they have no predators, rather than something innate to their species. This article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_tameness calls it 'island tameness'.

Comment: Actually, "tame" itself might be the closest thing to a canonical word for this that we have in English, but unfortunately it means alot of other things as well.

Comment: Yeah, ‘‘tame’’ fails because apex predators (e.g., lions, tigers and bears) aren’t afraid of humans, but they are hardly tame.